# How to update TFS user display name with C#

Tags: c#, tfs

I can retrieve list of users from TFS with following C# code. However, I want to change and persist display name of the users. Here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        TfsConfigurationServer tcs = new TfsConfigurationServer(new Uri("http://tfsserver:8080/tfs"));

        IIdentityManagementService ims = tcs.GetService<IIdentityManagementService>();

        TeamFoundationIdentity tfi = ims.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.AccountName, "[TEAM FOUNDATION]\\Team Foundation Valid Users", MembershipQuery.Expanded, ReadIdentityOptions.None);

        TeamFoundationIdentity[] ids = ims.ReadIdentities(tfi.Members, MembershipQuery.None, ReadIdentityOptions.None);

        foreach (TeamFoundationIdentity id in ids)
        {
            if (id.Descriptor.IdentityType == "System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity")
            {
                var displayName = id.DisplayName;

                // Now I would like to change this displayName and persist the change ??? 
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks
Rusho

Answer (score 1):

As you have pointed out just first use `ReadIdentities` in [IIdentityManagementService Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/ff735609(v%3Dvs.120)) You could take a look at below code snippet which converts identity.DisplayName from Patrick Lu  to Test User .

```
        var sec = _tfs.GetService<IGroupSecurityService>();
        var vcs = _tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();

        Identity[] appGroups = sec.ListApplicationGroups(vcs.GetTeamProject(_selectedTeamProject).ArtifactUri.AbsoluteUri);

        foreach (Identity group in appGroups)
        {
            Identity[] groupMembers = sec.ReadIdentities(SearchFactor.Sid, new string[] { group.Sid }, QueryMembership.Expanded);

            foreach (Identity member in groupMembers)
            {
                if (member.Members != null)
                {
                    foreach (string memberSid in member.Members)
                    {
                        Identity memberInfo = sec.ReadIdentity(SearchFactor.Sid, memberSid, QueryMembership.Expanded);

                        if (memberInfo.DisplayName.ToUpper() == "Patrick Lu")
                        {
                            memberInfo.DisplayName = "Test User ";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Make sure you have enough permission to do this.

Comment: Thanks PatrickLu! I understood that how to load display name of member. However, i want to persist (save the changes of display name back to data base). Is there method available to perform that operation?

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT how to save memberInfo.DisplayName changes value in to TFS database?

Comment: @Rusho Have go through the official link. Honestly, didn't find any related info. But have you tried with  above code snipper which provide by a MVP `foreach (string memberSid in member.Members)
                    {
                        Identity memberInfo = sec.ReadIdentity(SearchFactor.Sid, memberSid, QueryMembership.Expanded);

                        if (memberInfo.DisplayName.ToUpper() == "Patrick Lu")
                        {
                            memberInfo.DisplayName = "Test User ";
                        }
                    }`

Comment: @PatrickLu, Unfortunately that did not work!  However, thanks for your cooperation.